# Django class based views with url issue

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I'm trying to get to grips with class based views.

I have urls.py as follows:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('homework.views',

(r'^index/$', 'index'),
url(r'^(?P<sub_slug>\w+)/$', NavListView.as_view(), name='nav'),
url(r'^(?P<sub_slug>\w+)/(?P<class_grp_slug>\w+)/$', SubNavListView.as_view(), name='subnav'),

url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),)
```

I have my views.py:

```
# Subject navigation
class NavListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'templates/home.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.subject = Subject.objects.all()
        return self.subject

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(NavListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['subjects'] = self.subject
        return context

# Class group navigation
class SubNavListView(NavListView):

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.group = Group.objects.filter(subject__name__iexact=self.kwargs['sub_slug'])
        return self.group

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(NavListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['groups'] = self.group
        return context
```

In my 'templates/home.html' I have:

```
{% extends 'templates/base.html' %}
{% load url from future %}

{% block nav-menu-items %}
<ul class="nav">
    {% for sub in subjects %}
    <li class=""><a href="{% url 'nav' sub_slug %}">{{ sub }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Add Subject</a></li>
</ul>
{% endblock nav-menu-items %}

{% block class_groups_nav %}
<div class="tabbable">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    {% for group in groups %}
    <li>
      <a data-toggle="tab" href="{% url 'subnav' sub_slug class_grp_slug %}">{{ group }}</a>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
    <li><a href="#">Add</a></li>
  </ul>
{% endblock class_groups_nav %}
```

I'm trying to achieve a 'nav' of subjects, then a 'subnav' below showing a tab for each class group for the subject selected in the navigation above.

I've tried different ways of doing this such as making Subject.objects.all() available as context processors. I have also attempted to subclass NavListView so I can inherit the previous context, making them available in SubNavListView.

At the moment, I'm getting a NoReverseMatch error where the url named 'nav' is not passing the sub_slug and so I can't use it in the url in the template.

Any thoughts on getting this working?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `Subject` model has field named `slug` in it, you need to update your code to

```
<li class=""><a href="{% url 'nav' sub.slug %}">{{ sub }}</a></li>
```

ie. pass an appropriate parameter to `{%url ... %}`. Change `sub.slug` to whatever field name you want to refer to.

If you want to, you can also do `{% url 'nav' sub_slug=sub.slug %}`.

You are trying to pass `sub_slug`, but which is not defined in the template context, and result in empty string. So `nav` url will not get any parameter.

I see similar problem in your other `{%url ...%}` tags in the template.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, are the named parts of the url <sub_slug> and <class_grp_slug>, passed as *args to the function, but not into the context when the template is rendered?

Comment: @puffin, yes, `{% url ...%}` expects name of url and value that needs to be passed to view (if any defined in url pattern) not the variable name.